# Audio plays fast and acute

Tags: video-editor

I register an audio track from Audacity and export to wav
At that stage sound is OK

But when I load in Openshot sound like fast and very acute, voice is very strange.

I don't understand what happen and what to do

Comment: Welcome! What sample rate is the file exported from Audacity? What sample rate is Openshot expecting?

Comment: Audacity: 44 100
Openshot: 44 100

Concerning Openshot not sure in fact. I went to file property in project files tab

Comment: by playing with sampling rate I found a compromise a little bit better

Comment: Try 48 kHz in Audacity. That's what video usually expects.